# Converting the results of a column into a single row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot

I have the following table:

```
Name           Rating
Engineering    1
Financials     3
Scope          1
Schedule       2
Risks          3
People         3
```

I would like the output to be as follows:

```
Engineering  Financials  Scope  Schedule  Risks  People
1            3           1      2         3      3
```

Using SQL query only. Can someone help me to get the correct output?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Actually, it's not even a question.

Comment: What have you tried? This is a question and answer site, not a *do my code for me site*.

Comment: @woz: What's with the rollback?

Comment: Now qstn is clear to you

Comment: @user1882442 It would help a lot to know what you have tried, what your table structure is, and what that output means.  Are those arbitrary numbers?  Counts?  Averages?

Comment: @Matt To me, it wasn't clear what the OP wanted.

Comment: table structure is there the first one with Name & Rating.

Comment: some names are there according to which they have been rated, so ihave to convert that into tabular format.

Comment: if you are really using sql-server you should have a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: @Puskar: welcome to StackOverflow, glad this site has been useful to you! Please consider improving your question (even though you already received good answers) so it may help other people in the future. See [here](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) for tips on how to improve your question. Good luck!

Comment: And StackOverflow's own [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) can be helpful to you as well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) the data. SQL server has a `PIVOT` function that can perform this for you. To perform the `PIVOT` you need to decide what aggregate function to use.  In my sample, I used `MAX()` but you can use `SUM()`, etc.

If you do not have a pivot function then you can can use an aggregate function with a `CASE` statement to do this.

**Aggregate/CASE version:** This version requires that you hard-code all of the names into the columns.

```
select 
  max(case when name = 'Engineering' then rating end) Engineering,
  max(case when name = 'Financials' then rating end) Financials,
  max(case when name = 'Scope' then rating end) Scope,
  max(case when name = 'Schedule' then rating end) Schedule,
  max(case when name = 'Risks' then rating end) Risks,
  max(case when name = 'People' then rating end) People
from yourtable
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/334cd/1)

**Static PIVOT version:** You will hard code the values of the names into this query

```
select *
from
(
  select name, rating
  from yourtable
) src
pivot
(
  max(rating)
  for name in ([Engineering], [Financials], [Scope],
               [Schedule], [Risks], [People])
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/334cd/6)

The above versions work great if you have a known number of columns, but if your `name` values are unknown, then you can use dynamic sql to `PIVOT` the data.

**Dynamic PIVOT version:**

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(Name) 
                    from yourtable
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT ' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select name, rating
                from yourtable
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(rating)
                for name in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/334cd/7)

All three versions will produce the same result:

```
| ENGINEERING | FINANCIALS | SCOPE | SCHEDULE | RISKS | PEOPLE |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|           1 |          3 |     1 |        2 |     3 |      3 |
```

Comment: @Puskar if any of the answers are helpful for you be sure to accept via the checkmark on the left of it.

Comment: @bluefeet-ok i clicked on the checkmark....does it gives nay feedback or helps you in some way?

Comment: @bluefeet--Thanks for the info. Actually i am using this site for the 1st time and i loved it.