# How to convert diagonal rows into a single row?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

This is my table. The numbers are coming diagonally.

```
Engineering  Financials  Scope  Schedule  Risks  People
--------------------------------------------------------
1            NULL        NULL   NULL      NULL   NULL
NULL         0           NULL   NULL      NULL   NULL
NULL         NULL        0      NULL      NULL   NULL
NULL         NULL        NULL   0         NULL   NULL
NULL         NULL        NULL   NULL      0      NULL
2            NULL        NULL   NULL      NULL   NULL
NULL         4           NULL   NULL      NULL   NULL
NULL         NULL        3      NULL      NULL   NULL
NULL         NULL        NULL   4         NULL   NULL
NULL         NULL        NULL   NULL      4      NULL
NULL         NULL        NULL   NULL      NULL   0
0            NULL        NULL   NULL      NULL   NULL
NULL         0           NULL   NULL      NULL   NULL
NULL         NULL        0      NULL      NULL   NULL
NULL         NULL        NULL   0         NULL   NULL
NULL         NULL        NULL   NULL      0      NULL
NULL         NULL        NULL   NULL      NULL   0
0            NULL        NULL   NULL      NULL   NULL
NULL         0           NULL   NULL      NULL   NULL
NULL         NULL        0      NULL      NULL   NULL
NULL         NULL        NULL   0         NULL   NULL
NULL         NULL        NULL   NULL      0      NULL
NULL         NULL        NULL   NULL      NULL   0
1            NULL        NULL   NULL      NULL   NULL
NULL         0           NULL   NULL      NULL   NULL
NULL         NULL        5      NULL      NULL   NULL
NULL         NULL        NULL   4         NULL   NULL
NULL         NULL        NULL   NULL      3      NULL
NULL         NULL        NULL   NULL      NULL   3
```

I would like those to come in this output:

```
Engineering  Financials  Scope  Schedule  Risks  People
--------------------------------------------------------
1            0           0      0         0      NULL
2            4           3      4         4      0
0            0           0      0         0      0
0            0           0      0         0      0
0            0           0      0         0      0
1            0           5      4         3      3
```

Actually I want to convert those diagonal rows into a single row for each section.

Comment: Please edit your question and use the code tool ({}) to format the table.

Comment: Is there a key column which binds the diagonal rows together?  In other words, how do you know the first 5 rows are related to each other and the next 6 are related?

Comment: @Akhil---how to edit my questions, i was not able to do that

Comment: You can edit the question by clicking on _edit_, right beneath the tags at the bottom of your question.

Comment: @Puskar did you resolve this issue with your pivot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The aggregation you want as a result seems to be based on the order of the rows in your table. In tables, row order should not matter and it is dangerous to assume that the order will stay the same.

So unless you have not shown us the complete source table yet (with for example a `Section` column in it), it is hard to give you a helpful answer to this question.

---

**Edit:**

If you *have* a `Section` column, you could use the following query to get the result you want:

```
SELECT   Section
         ,SUM(Engineering) AS Engineering
         ,SUM(Financials) AS Financials
         ,SUM(Scope) AS Scope
         ,SUM(Schedule) AS Schedule
         ,SUM(Risks) AS Risks
         ,SUM(People) AS People
FROM     YourTable
GROUP BY Section;
```

Instead of using the `SUM` function to aggregate your data, you could also use `MAX` or another function, depending on the data and what you want to get out of it.

Answer (score 4):

This is too long to be a comment so I am answering.

It is not exactly clear where your data is coming from, if that is the table of data or from a query.  Your [previous question was about a `PIVOT`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13744503/need-help-for-converting-results-of-a-column-into-a-single-row-in-sql-server) and the data you provided matches that same data so I am going to guess that this is coming from a that query.

If you are using a `PIVOT` query, and you have too many fields in the subquery this type of behavior can happen.

**Sample Data Query 1**:

```
CREATE TABLE yourtable ([Name] varchar(11), [Rating] int);

INSERT INTO yourtable ([Name], [Rating])
VALUES
    ('Engineering', 1),
    ('Financials', 3),
    ('Scope', 1),
    ('Schedule', 2),
    ('Risks', 3),
    ('People', 3);
```

**PIVOT** that will provide the correct result

```
select *
from
(
  select name, rating
  from yourtable
) src
pivot
(
  max(rating)
  for name in ([Engineering], [Financials], [Scope],
               [Schedule], [Risks], [People])
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/334cd/6)

Results in the following:

```
| ENGINEERING | FINANCIALS | SCOPE | SCHEDULE | RISKS | PEOPLE |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|           1 |          3 |     1 |        2 |     3 |      3 |
```

The above would be the correct syntax since you have one row for the entries.  Now if I alter this query slightly, you will see the difference:

**Sample Data Query 2**:  I have added an `id` field to this

```
CREATE TABLE yourtable([Name] varchar(11), [Rating] int, id int);

INSERT INTO yourtable([Name], [Rating], id)
VALUES
    ('Engineering', 1, 1),
    ('Financials', 3, 2),
    ('Scope', 1, 3), 
    ('Schedule', 2, 4),
    ('Risks', 3, 5),
    ('People', 3, 6);
```

If I perform a `PIVOT` and include this `ID` field, the result will look like yours.

**PIVOT**:

```
select [Engineering], [Financials], [Scope], [Schedule], [Risks], [People]
from
(
  select name, rating, id  -- notice the addition of the id column
  from yourtable
) src
pivot
(
  max(rating)
  for name in ([Engineering], [Financials], [Scope],
               [Schedule], [Risks], [People])
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/90931/1)

Result:

```
| ENGINEERING | FINANCIALS |  SCOPE | SCHEDULE |  RISKS | PEOPLE |
------------------------------------------------------------------
|           1 |     (null) | (null) |   (null) | (null) | (null) |
|      (null) |          3 | (null) |   (null) | (null) | (null) |
|      (null) |     (null) |      1 |   (null) | (null) | (null) |
|      (null) |     (null) | (null) |        2 | (null) | (null) |
|      (null) |     (null) | (null) |   (null) |      3 | (null) |
|      (null) |     (null) | (null) |   (null) | (null) |      3 |
```

As you can see adding this extra column reproduced the issue you are getting.  My suggestion would be to post your table structure and then the query you are using to get your result.  From this then we would be able to assist you.

Comment: +1, and more information would help indeed! The previous question is found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13744503/need-help-for-converting-results-of-a-column-into-a-single-row-in-sql-server).

Comment: This is a fantastic explanation of this 'diagonal' behavior. Thanks!